# html form button link to url

Tags: html

I have a simple search form with a box and a button.

```
<form action = "/search/" method = "get">
<input id = "search_box" type ="text" name = "location" value placeholder = "Where are you?" />
<input id = "search_button" type="submit" value = 'Go' />
</form>
```

This sends me to `/search/?location=whatever`

How do I get this to send me to `/search/whatever` instead? - i.e. no GET data, just an URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot rewrite the form post methods like that. A way to do this efficiently is through a `.htaccess` at the root.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^search\/?location=(.*)$ search/$1
```

This changes `/search/?location=whatever` to `/search/whatever`

Or, If you are looking for a complicated JS solution. Here is one using jQuery

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    var search = $("#search_box").val(); //get the element
    $(this).attr("action", $(this).attr("action")+search);  //attach to the post url
    $("#search_id").remove();  //remove the element, so it doesnot get sent
    console.log($(this).attr('action')); //check the console, if the action was changed and yes it was
    //return false; //continues the post to the new url if commented
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/rdJrJ/)

Comment: That's assuming he has an Apache based server, but yes. +1.